# android fragment isRemoved method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment-lifecycle

There is a `isRemoving` method for fragments in android. Per the documentation, it only tells when a fragment is in the process of being removed. But I need to know whether a fragment has already been removed. Is there a way to find this out? I am using api level 11.

Answer (score 0):

For what purpose are you using this method?

There are other convinience methods like `isVisible()`.

If you want to be sure that you are safe to perform any action inside of `fragment`, it's better to check `getActivity()`, as it is the only one call that will tell you true when your fragment is legal to perform action.